# Highlight a row of a table with JQuery / Bootstrap using anchors

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, anchor, highlight, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using Bootstrap (Twitter) and JQuery. I have a table with some data and each row has an id. I have a typeahead to search data in my table. When I select a data in my typeahead, I would like to highlight the correct row, that why I use the anchors. But, I don't know how to highlight the row.

Here my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#typeahead').change(function() {
        window.location = "#" + $(this).val();
        //highlighting the row...
    });
});
```

This HTML code is just for testing:

```
<a href="#row1">Row1</a>
<a href="#row2">Row2</a>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here the code for the typeahead:

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search a name" data-items="4" data-source='[
<?php for($i = 0 ; $i < count($typeahead) ; $i++) {

if($i+1 == count($typeahead))
echo '"'.$typeahead[$i].'"';
else
echo '"'.$typeahead[$i].'",';
} 

?>]'>
```

Here the content of the typeahead array:

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search a name" data-items="4" data-source='["Christophe Chantraine","Toto Tuteur","Henris Michaux","Robert Patinson","Benjamin Brégnard","Jean-Charles Terzis","Ludovic Dermience","Claude Dianga"]'>
```

Here is a sample code to introduce my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/TK7QP/6/

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `$typeahead` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the id attribute on your table rows, change it to data-name instead. Example:

```
<tr data-name="Christophe Chantraine">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
```

Add this CSS to your stylesheet:

```
.table-hover tbody tr.selected > td {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Then change your jQuery code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#typeahead').change(function() {
        window.location = "#" + $(this).val();
        //highlighting the row...
        $('tr[data-name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

It takes slightly longer to find an element by a data attribute than an id, but it won't be noticeable unless you have a ridiculous amount of table rows. It's easiest to use data attributes because you would have to "slugify" the names to use them as ids, meaning remove all spaces, special characters etc.

**----Alternate answer using id attribute so you can link to table rows----**

To do this, you will need to replace the spaces in your names. Here's an example of how you could do that using PHP:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr id="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', 'Christophe Chantraine');?>">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', 'Benjamin Brégnard');?>">
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When you link to the rows, your anchors will also need to have underscores:

`<a href="#Christophe_Chantraine">Christophe Chantraine</a>`

Then your jQuery should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#typeahead').change(function() {
        $('tr').removeClass('selected'); // remove class from other rows
        $('#' + $(this).val().replace(' ', '_')).addClass('selected');
        window.location = "#" +  $(this).val().replace(' ', '_');
    });
});
```

To add a transition effect you could do something like this in your CSS. Change the length of the transition if one second is too long:

```
.table-hover tbody tr.selected > td {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: background 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background 1s linear;
    transition: background 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't works. I added the code of my typeahead. Thank you for your help!

Comment: In fact, I have to select "tr" where id = $(this).val(); But I don't know how... I'm searching for...

Comment: How you select the tr might depend on whether the td content exactly matches the typeahead result or not, so you should post the $typeahead array

Comment: Yes, indeed, the name select in the typeahead is exactely the same as my id in my table. So, something like this: <tr id="Christophe Chantraine">...</tr>

Comment: Now it's beginning to come clear! The problem is that id attributes can't have spaces or special characters in them. They can only have letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens, colons, and periods, and they must start with a letter. I'll update my answer above with what I think is the easiest solution.

Comment: -_- of course yes. It's really kinf of you to help me. Thank you!

Comment: Np. Do you need to be able to link to the table rows by their anchors? If you do, I'll have to change my answer again. Also, if you do, tell me if you are using HTML5 as your doctype or not.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm using HTML5 yes. Now, I'm trying to make an animation wth CSS3 to have a "fade in" effect.

Comment: Ok, if you need to link you'll have to use the id attribute, but the fact that you're using HTML5 makes it a bit easier because you can use special characters in id attributes there. I have left my original answer but added a new one to the end. I also added a line to deselect other rows when a new one is selected.